# How to resolve 'FwfhTextStyle' error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, mobile-development

My app is not building because of this error and I am not able to understand the error. I tried 'flutter upgrade' and 'flutter get' but nothing was helpful.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM A127F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fwfh_text_style-2.7.3+2/lib/fwfh_text_style.dart:11:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'FwfhTextStyle' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TextStyle.fontVariations
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class FwfhTextStyle extends _TextStyleProxy {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:789:33: Context: 'TextStyle.fontVariations' is defined here.
  final List<ui.FontVariation>? fontVariations;
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/vrs/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/vrs/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 15):

Please try it out by upgrading the dependency `flutter pub upgrade fwfh_text_style`

Answer (score 14):

After I upgraded to Flutter `3.3.0` this error appearing to me

After some searching I resolved it by run upgrade for packages in my project

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

then

```
flutter clean 

flutter pub get
```

Comment: This error was occurring because of a "Better Player". I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add [fwfh_text_style](https://pub.dev/packages/fwfh_text_style) this plugin in your project if not added. It works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solved it for me.

As a reference for others: I was using BetterPlayer library, which is largely abandoned atm. The problem came from its dependencies. Adding the library mentioned above solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about the definition of `final List<ui.FontVariation>? fontVariations;`

Whether it's defined at the last indexes or it's not defined at all.

I'd do something like that to prevent an error. `List<ui.FontVariation> fontVariations = [];`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `flutter upgrade` and then `flutter clean` but it didn't work for me.

I then run this command `flutter pub outdated` and it worked good.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `rm -rf ~/.pub-cache` and then `flutter pub get` ‍♂️